# How can I create a user input loop for a Guess the Number game between 1-100?

Tags: python, while-loop, user-input

```
#Guess the number

from random import *
correct_number = randint(1, 100)
#print(correct_number)

def guess(user_guess):
    while user_input != correct_number:
        if user_guess == correct_number:
            return f"{correct_number} is the correct number! Congratulations! Would you like to play again?"
        elif user_guess > correct_number:
            return "Guess a lower number\n"
            user_input = int(user_input("Guess a number between 1 and 100.\n"))
        else:
            return "Guess a higher number\n"
            user_input = int(user_input("Guess a number between 1 and 100.\n"))

"""user_input = ""
while user_input != correct_number:
    user_input = input("Hey user, guess a number between 1 and 100.\n")"""

user_input = input("Hey user, guess a number between 1 and 100.\n")
user_input_guess = int(user_input)

value = guess(user_input_guess)
print(value)
```

I have the bulk of the code ready. I just can't nail the user input loop. Each time I guess a number it exits the code.

Comment: why do you return if the number is not correct? I think instead of return you should use print

Answer (score 0):

```
from random import randint

correct_number = randint(1, 100)

user_input = ""
while user_input != correct_number:
    user_input = int(input("Hey user, guess a number between 1 and 100.\n"))
```

No need to use functions. You forgot to convert the input to an int in the code inside the comment so that's why it wasn't working

Comment: Thank you! But then the output won't give me the written out hints of guessing higher or lower: Hey user, guess a number between 1 and 100.
23
Hey user, guess a number between 1 and 100.

Answer (score 0):

`return` will break the define so you should return the data when the user guess the correct answer

```
from random import *
correct_number = randint(1, 100)
#print(correct_number)

def guess(user_guess):
    while user_guess != correct_number:
        if user_guess == correct_number:
            return f"{correct_number} is the correct number! Congratulations! Would you like to play again?"
        elif user_guess > correct_number:
            print("Guess a lower number\n")
            user_guess = int(input("Guess a number between 1 and 100.\n"))
        else:
            print("Guess a higher number\n")
            user_guess = int(input("Guess a number between 1 and 100.\n"))

"""user_input = ""
while user_input != correct_number:
    user_input = input("Hey user, guess a number between 1 and 100.\n")"""

user_input = input("Hey user, guess a number between 1 and 100.\n")
user_input_guess = int(user_input)

value = guess(user_input_guess)
print(value)
```

This will work

Comment: Thank you! But then the output won't give me the written out hints of guessing higher or lower, example output code: Hey user, guess a number between 1 and 100. 23 Hey user, guess a number between 1 and 100.

Comment: I think you put the comment on wrong person... Btw I solve the code error of reffering a variable before assignment . If you find any bug , please let me know.